# C++ and SDL Can't get more than 3 Images on the Screen at One Time

Tags: c++, image, keyboard, sdl

I am trying to make an onscreen keyboard program, wherein when I press a given key a picture of it shows up on the screen, but I found that when I pressed A, B, C, and D altogether on my keyboard, only A, B, and C showed up.  When I tried to press the keys in a different order, there was always one letter that didn't show up.  Nothing I found online answered my question.  My code (I only have A, B, C, and D being detected at the moment):

```
Uint8 *key = SDL_GetKeyState(NULL);

SDL_Surface *alphabet = SDL_LoadBMP("keys/letters/alphabet.bmp");

SDL_Rect A;
A.x = 150;
A.y = 156;
A.w = 106;
A.h = 123;

SDL_Rect B;
B.x = 322;
B.y = 160;
B.w = 106;
B.h = 123;

SDL_Rect b;
b.x = 110;

SDL_Rect C;
C.x = 525;
C.y = 162;
C.w = 106;
C.h = 123;

SDL_Rect c;
c.x = 220;

SDL_Rect D;
D.x = 735;
D.y = 163;
D.w = 106;
D.h = 123;

SDL_Rect d;
d.x = 330;

while(running == true)
{
    SDL_PollEvent(&eventhandler);
    if(eventhandler.type == SDL_QUIT)
        running = false;

    SDL_FillRect(screen,NULL,0xFFFFFF);

    if(key[SDLK_a])
        SDL_BlitSurface(alphabet,&A,screen,NULL);

    if(key[SDLK_b])
        SDL_BlitSurface(alphabet,&B,screen,&b);

    if(key[SDLK_c])
        SDL_BlitSurface(alphabet,&C,screen,&c);

    if(key[SDLK_d])
        SDL_BlitSurface(alphabet,&D,screen,&d);

    SDL_Flip(screen);
}`
```

Comment: With many keyboards you cannot input more than 3 keys at a time. This is called [ghosting](http://www.microsoft.com/appliedsciences/antighostingexplained.mspx).

Answer (score 0):

I'm fairly certain this is to do with hardware rather software, keyboards just won't get more input than that at one time.
Instead of using keystates you could use an SDL_Event and toggle bools on/off in the program to control each of the button textures.

Answer (score 0):

You need to query your event in a loop, because with the method you are using, you only get one event per frame, even if there is 20 events waiting in the poll, you are just poping the last one at each frame.

Consider to change your code to this

```
SDL_Event evt;
while(SDL_PollEvent(&evt))
{
   //event handling here
}
```

And by using this

```
Uint8 *key = SDL_GetKeyState(NULL);
```

You need to get you keystate at each frame... Not only at the beginning.
You need to use SDL_PumpEvents to update your array.
 PumpEvents is suppose to be called by PollEvent. But, I found the loop with PollEvent a better solution than using a KeyboardState array.